# SQL Snowflake Column Condition Check

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Basically, I am trying to write a query against a table such like the following.  Here we have Plans of either Free, Plus or Premium (in the example below I only show free and plus plans). Is it possible to return records where an ID that was original a 'Free' plan has changed to either a 'plus' or 'premium'? This would be caught via a binary condition check column 'ID Upgraded'

In the case of the Data table below

```
ID  Name  Plan  Date
1   Sam   Free 1/1/2021 
3   Amy   Free 1/2/2021
4   Tom   Free 1/5/2021
3   Amy   Plus 1/8/2021
2   Kim   Free 1/9/2021
4   Tom   Plus 1/10/2021
```

Output:

```
ID  Name  Plan  Date.    Upgrade?
1   Sam   Free 1/1/2021   0
3   Amy   Free 1/2/2021   0
4   Tom   Free 1/5/2021   0
3   Amy   Plus 1/8/2021   1
2   Kim   Free 1/9/2021   0 
4   Tom   Plus 1/10/2021  1
```

In my attempt to accomplish this I was only able to get as far as **ISOLATING** user IDs that are repeats in a separate table with the use of a variety of CTEs. While this can kind of work I believe for analysis the output as shown above would be a much cleaner option.

As am writing this request I imagine we need to use some kind of count feature to count if a value repeats then check to see if plan string value has changed?

My logic is as follows:

```
With data as ( 
    select id, name, plan, date, count(id) as cnt
    from   TABLE
   )

select *
from data
where cnt > 1 -- All repeating ids
**and plan changes help needed here**
```

Edit: The method I tried above resulted in columns not being counted by the count function. needs work

Edit: also tried the following but no avail!

```
 Row_Number() Over (Partition By id Order By count(t.id) Asc) As DupCounter,
```

Comment: The title mentions Postgres, but the tags also show Snowflake. Which one is this question for?

Comment: apologies snowflake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LAG`, which is one of [window (a.k.a. analytical) functions](http://postgres.org/docs/current/functions-window.html).

Initial data:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE plans(ID integer,  Name text,  Plan text,  Date date);
COPY plans FROM STDIN WITH (FORMAT CSV);
1,Sam,Free,1/1/2021
3,Amy,Free,1/2/2021
4,Tom,Free,1/5/2021
3,Amy,Plus,1/8/2021
2,Kim,Free,1/9/2021
4,Tom,Plus,1/10/2021
\.
```

Query:

```
SELECT ID,Name,Plan,Date,
  LAG(Plan) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date) AS PrevPlan 
FROM plans;
```

Result:

```
 id | name | plan |    date    | prevplan 
----+------+------+------------+----------
  1 | Sam  | Free | 2021-01-01 | NULL
  2 | Kim  | Free | 2021-09-01 | NULL
  3 | Amy  | Free | 2021-02-01 | NULL
  3 | Amy  | Plus | 2021-08-01 | Free
  4 | Tom  | Free | 2021-05-01 | NULL
  4 | Tom  | Plus | 2021-10-01 | Free
(6 rows)
```

Query:

```
SELECT ID,Name,Plan,Date,PrevPlan,
  CASE WHEN Plan>PrevPlan then 'Upgrade'
       WHEN Plan<Prevplan then 'Downgrade' END AS flag
FROM (SELECT *, LAG(Plan) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date) AS PrevPlan
      FROM plans) AS p;
```

Result:

```
 id | name | plan |    date    | prevplan |  flag   
----+------+------+------------+----------+---------
  1 | Sam  | Free | 2021-01-01 | NULL     | NULL
  2 | Kim  | Free | 2021-09-01 | NULL     | NULL
  3 | Amy  | Free | 2021-02-01 | NULL     | NULL
  3 | Amy  | Plus | 2021-08-01 | Free     | Upgrade
  4 | Tom  | Free | 2021-05-01 | NULL     | NULL
  4 | Tom  | Plus | 2021-10-01 | Free     | Upgrade
(6 rows)
```

To satisfy your exact requirement and flag *only when a 'Free' changes to either a 'plus' or 'premium'*, use this:

```
SELECT ID,Name,Plan,Date,PrevPlan,
  CASE
    WHEN PrevPlan='Free' THEN CASE
      WHEN Plan IN ('Plus', 'Premium') THEN 'Upgrade'
    END
    WHEN PrevPlan IN('Plus', 'Premium') THEN CASE
      WHEN Plan='Free' THEN 'Downgrade'
    END
  END as flag
FROM (
  SELECT *, LAG(Plan) 
  OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date) AS PrevPlan
  FROM plans
) AS p;
```

Answer (score 1):

So because 'Free' is less than 'Plus' which is also less than 'Premium' you can use this SQL

```
WITH data AS (
   SELECT * FROM VALUES
    (1,  'Sam',   'Free', '2021-01-01'),
    (3,   'Amy',   'Free', '2021-01-02'),
    (4,   'Tom',   'Free', '2021-01-05'),
    (3,   'Amy',   'Plus', '2021-01-08'),
    (2,   'Kim',   'Free', '2021-01-09'),
    (4,   'Tom',  'Plus', '2021-01-10')
    v(ID, Name, Plan,  Date)
)
SELECT id
    ,name
    ,plan
    ,date
    ,plan > lag(plan)over(partition by id order by date) as upgrade  
    ,plan < lag(plan)over(partition by id order by date) as downgrade
FROM data
ORDER BY id,date;
```

which gives:

```
ID   NAME   PLAN    DATE          UPGRADE  DOWNGRADE
1    Sam    Free    2021-01-01        
2    Kim    Free    2021-01-09        
3    Amy    Free    2021-01-02        
3    Amy    Plus    2021-01-08    TRUE    FALSE
4    Tom    Free    2021-01-05        
4    Tom    Plus    2021-01-10    TRUE    FALSE
```

So if you are just wanting to know "has someone ever upgraded" the a follow on

```
QUALIFY upgrade
```

but if you are want to know the users current state because they have have transitioned from free to plan and back to free you should use something like

```
WITH data AS (
   SELECT * FROM VALUES
    (1,  'Sam',   'Free', '2021-01-01'),
    (3,   'Amy',   'Free', '2021-01-02'),
    (4,   'Tom',   'Free', '2021-01-05'),
    (3,   'Amy',   'Plus', '2021-01-08'),
    (2,   'Kim',   'Free', '2021-01-09'),
    (4,   'Tom',  'Plus', '2021-01-10')
    v(ID, Name, Plan,  Date)
)
SELECT id
    ,name
    ,plan
    ,date
    ,plan > lag(plan)over(partition by id order by date) as upgrade  
    ,plan < lag(plan)over(partition by id order by date) as downgrade
FROM data
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by id order by date desc) = 1 
ORDER BY id, date;
```

Answer (score 1):

You wan to know if there were any "frees" before a "plus" or "premium".  I would use window functions, but not limit this to `lag()`.  So:

```
select t.*,
       (case when sum(case when plan = 'Free' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by name order by date) > 0 and
                  plan in ('Plus', 'Premium')
             then 'Upgrade'
        end)
from t;
```

Comment: the problem with this is 'free' -> 'plus' -> 'premium' -> 'plus' will give you three upgrades events, when the last was a downgrade. It really all depends if they are wanting to know when the transitions happened. Also a 'plus' -> 'premium' will not be a upgrade, as there is not free.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim . . . That was how I read the question:  "Is it possible to return records where an ID that was original a 'Free' plan has changed to either a 'plus' or 'premium'? ".

Comment: fair call, I guess I made assumptions of the nature of the question someone would be trying to answer, and the value of the different result sets. As a whole the question has a few gaps with respect to the intent.